# Update PDO Driver for SQLite for php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a server with this configuration:

centos 6.4

PHP 5.4

SQLite Library  3.6.20 (this is from phpinfo())

I **desperately** need to upgrade the sqlite library. I need to access from php a sqlite library. It seems that that database was created with sqlite 3.7. When I try to open it from php, I get this error "file is encrypted or is not a database". Updating that driver will solve the problem

Php was installed with the command yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm

I have found some answers like yum install php5-sqlite, it seems that this is an old command. Usually I find some outdated answers. I would need something to work with php 5.4. Installing with pecl did not work either.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have no issue reading a sqliteDB generated with SQLite 3.8 (Fedora) from an CentOS 6 box with SQLite 3.6

```
php -r 'var_dump(
  $db=new sqlite3("/tmp/test.sqlite"),
  $q=$db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master")); 
  foreach ($q->fetchArray() as $r) var_dump($r);'
```

With PDO:

```
php -r 'var_dump(
  $db=new PDO("sqlite:/tmp/test.sqlite"),
  $q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master"),
  $q->fetchAll()); '
```

Of course, you need to use "sqlite3" or "pdo_sqlite" extension, not the old deprecated "sqlite" one.